# Save true/false match() data from loop in dataframe

Tags: r

I know there are a lot of posts on how to save data out of loops to data frames, but i've been having some trouble making it work for me. Currently i am only able to get my data using print, but would like for it to instead be put into a data frame. I can't predict how many lines of data or responses per line (although I just need a single true/false) it will give.

Suggestions on how to get the P loop to output data to a dataframe?

```
max <- max(x$a)
for (n in 1:max) {
  print(n)
  #right now i'm just printing the iteration and data to console
  result <- x[x$a==n,"b"]
   test <- unique(as.numeric(unlist(result)))
   #Below is the loop i'd like to save the data from  
   for (P in test) 
     print({
       ar  <- x[x$b==P & x$a!=n,"a"]
       ar1 <- sapply(unique(as.numeric(unlist(ar))), 
                function(f) 
                  x[x$a==f & x$b!=P,"b"])
       af  <- sapply(ar1, function(f) any(match(f,result)))
     })
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: to clarify i'd like the output to be three columns: the iteration, the value of P, and the true/false statement from match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initiate an empty data frame:

```
results <- data.frame(it=numeric(), P=numeric(), value=logical())
```

And then instead of printing, just add this inside your loop:

```
results[nrow(results)+1,] <- list( [your 3 values separated by ","] )
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work, but I'm running into the problem that some values in the first loop output "integer(0)" which gets turned into "list()" by the match function. Resulting in this error: "Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero"

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could add a check like this: `value <- ifelse(identical(value, integer(0)), NA, value)`

Comment: Thanks! While this fixed the integer(0) issue, for my data that were working correctly it would collapse outputs that had more than one value (1,2,3) into just the first value (1). Thoughts on how to fix that?

Comment: Oh, right... Then this: `value <- if (identical(value, integer(0))) NA else value`

Comment: Thank you! that worked. I think my final question is: I get very different results for different starting numbers (n). for example 1 results in:<br> TRUE. <br> FALSE, <br> FALSE, TRUE <br> but 2 results just in "TRUE". So i'm still getting the error "  replacement element 3 has 2 rows to replace 1 rows". is there anyway to get the data table to accept such crazy data? Alternatively, i only care if any of the values under the iteration of 1 match true... i tried putting match(loop, true) around my second loop, but to no avail. Thank you so much!!

Comment: actually i was able to fix this by adding another "any(match(af,TRUE,nomatch=0)" to the last line. I also had your "results[nrow..." code in the middle of my second loop which was giving weird results -- moving it to the very end of the code works. Thanks again!